# unlocking a cracked phone through the computer?

Tags: usb-debugging

I cracked the screen on my Samsung Galaxy s6 Edge and now I can't unlock it. I have looked all over for a way to unlock my phone using a computer but to no avail. I have tried droid screen, some tools on xda forums and a google chrome app. None of them seem to detect my phone. I distinctly remember turning on usb debugging on my phone but I am not certain. Is there any way to check if usb debugging is enabled on my phone without actually opening it? Also if usb debugging is not enabled, is there still a way to control my phone screen through my computer? I have unsuccessfully tried to install ADB but after the first few steps of the installation I get lost in the  technicality of the language. My phone is not rooted. I am running windows 10 and I posses almost zero technical knowledge about the workings of android and how it connects to a computer. I would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction or explain what I need to do in simple language. Thanks!

Comment: Install adb like this :- 1. Google fastboot files 2.download them 3.unzip them 4. Hold shift and right click 5. Click open command prompt here 6. Type adb devices

Comment: adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
0815f845c6c12105        offline.                                                                                                     This is what it says. I have no idea what this means

Comment: Do you have root?

Comment: Also what errors you get on the tools like droid screen

Comment: Android SDK manager opens up with a bunch of stuff that it says I can install. I don't know which ones to install. It says done loading packages

Comment: Google for fastboot files

Answer (score 1):

Once the adb files are on your pc, all you have to do is run the command to list adb devices. If no results show up, your device does not have usb debugging enabled. If you get a result, an 8 digit number.. that means you have it enabled and the phone is connected. There is a way to enable usb debugging via command line but then, that is even nore technical. Save yourself the headache and unlock your phone with a usb mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Conect a usb mouse,  you will need a usb mouse with a usb type A to microusb adapter to connect the mouse directly to your phone, provided that you can still see the area of your screen needed to unlock your phone, even if touches arent being detected.

Comment: i'm looking for a software only way to resolve this.